# Получить количество изменений каждого файла по нужному пути

Tags: c#, git

К решению привязан git. Как можно получить количество изменений каждого конкретного файла в конкретном проекте с помощью C# и посчитать их сумму?

Задача для чего это всё делается: выводить пользователю версию программы. У меня возникла следующая идея: посчитать кол-во изменений файлов в решении в 2 проектах (.exe и .dll для него), которые являются связанными и используются при публикации и вывести пользователю это информацию

Comment: другие языки кроме c# не подойдут?

Comment: @Эникейщик Например? Вы говорите о создании какого-нибудь батника, который-бы вызывал "методы" git?

Comment: да что угодно. Просто странно, что именно "с помощью c#".

Comment: `libgit2` имеет C# биндинги. Но по сути вы хотите странного. Версия программы — версия её в Git, которая однозначно определяется хешом соответствующего комита. Зачем выдумывать велосипед?

Answer (score -1):

1. с помощью FOR перечисляем файлы в каталоге .\source
2. запрашиваем у гит коммиты по файлу, выводя каждый с новой строки
3. с помощью wc подсчитывае количество строк

CMD:

```
FOR /R .\Source %%F IN (*.cs) DO echo %%~nxF&&git log --oneline .\Source\%%~nxF |wc -l
```

Comment: `"wc" не является внутренней или внешней`. Операционная система - Windows

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/